# Como converter relatorios Delphi?

Tags: delphi-xe5

Alguém conhece alguma maneira de converter relatórios feitos em Delphi-5.0/QuickReport para o DlphiSE5 com o Fastreport? Obrigado

Comment: Se tens duas contas podes converter numa só usando esta página: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar nas uses do seu projeto a `unit` `ConverterQR2FR` e use isto:

```
conv := TConverterQr2Fr.Create;
conv.Source := QuickRep1;
conv.Target := FReport;
conv.Convert;
FReport.SaveToFile('converted_fromQR.fr3');
```

[Aqui você pode pegar a `unit` completa](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Delphi/borland.public.delphi.thirdpartytools.general/2007-04/msg00216.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado Júnior vou tentar.

Comment: @SergioDeToledoPiza se tens duas contas podes converter numa só usando esta página: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact